# Android application finish() from Async Subclass

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using an Async Class as a subclass. After the success successful completion, I want to go to an activity, suppose  ListActivity.

But after reach ListActivity, When I click on "back" it coming back to the previous activity itself. So I tried "finish()". But I am getting an error.

My code looks like.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(flags.equals(1)){
            Intent homepage = new Intent(GCMIntentService.this, ListActivity.class);
            homepage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(homepage);
            finish();
        }
        else {
```

Can any one have any idea about how to use finish() in Async Subclass ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post your error and stack trace

Comment: try `homepage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`

Comment: GCMIntentService.this.finish(); ?

Comment: @Geralt_Encore thats the activity that he's starting

Comment: @Vee actually, activity is the ListActivity

Comment: @Geralt_Encore Oh yep, you're right, forgot thats the context.

Comment: homepage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)‌​ not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`YourClassName.this.finish()` where `YourClassName` is the name of the class that contains the `AsyncTask`.

**EDIT:** `GCMIntentService` is actually an instance of `GCMBaseIntentService`, not an `Activity`.  Therefore it has no `finish()` method.  The correct way to stop a service is by calling `stopSelf()` (doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29)).  So, to stop your service you should call `GCMIntentService.this.stopSelf()`.  You probably don't need to do this because Android will most likely take care of it for you when you start the new `Activity`.

NOTE:  `GCMBaseIntentService` has been deprecated, and it's better now to use [Google Cloud Messaging API](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html).

Comment: Hi I am getting the following error When I tried this The method finish() is undefined for the type GCMIntentService

Comment: Is `GCMIntentService` an `Activity` or a `Service`?  What is it a subclass of?

Comment: GCMIntentService not an activity. Its for GCM like public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService  . Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your current activity after start the intent, calling `currentActivity.this.finish();`

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if(flags.equals(1)){
            Intent homepage = new Intent(GCMIntentService.this, ListActivity.class);
            homepage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(homepage);
            currentActivity.this.finish()
            ...
         }
```

Comment: Hi I am getting the following error When I tried this The method finish() is undefined for the type GCMIntentService when I tried GCMIntentService.this.finish(); any idea ? :(